# Semantic UI pop up with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, popup, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use the [Semantic's popup](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html#) with meteor

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'Movie_Info' _id=movie._id}}"><img src={{movie.HomePoster}} data-title="Title" data-content="Description"></a>


/*JS file*/
Template.Home_Page.events({

});

$('img')
    .popup({
      boundary: 'a',
    })
;
```

But it's not displaying the popup when I hover over the image... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did my answer helped you or is there still a problem with the code?

Answer (score 0):

In Blaze (default Template rendering engine of Meteor) you are using event mapping to attach events to your components.

TEMPLATE:

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'Movie_Info' _id=movie._id}}">
  <img src={{movie.HomePoster}} class="popup-target" data-title="Title" data-content="Description">
</a>
```

Note, that I added the `class="popup-target"` which will act as selector for our event listener.

JS:

```
Template.Home_Page.events({
  'mouseover .popup-target' (event, templateInstance) {
    // trigger popup using jquery here
    // event.currentTarget is the source of the event
    // in our case the image
    $(event.currentTarget).popup({
      boundary: 'a',
    })
  }
});
```

Read more here:

http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Event-Maps